# Alternative models of a hyperelliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, function-fields, positive-characteristic

I am studying some particular examples of hyperelliptic curves and their automorphism groups (from [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0811.0876), if it is of interest).

It is mentioned in the paper to understand the automorphism of some curves it is necessary to rewrite the defining equations such that only even powers of $x$ occur; i.e. find a model for the curve of the form
$$
y^2 = \sum_{i=0}^s a_{2i}x^{2i}. \qquad \qquad (1)
$$

The paper does not specify how one should do this, and I am struggling to do this with some of the curves given. I imagine there may be some techniques I am missing, so I wondered if anyone could help with one of the examples.

We suppose that we are working over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic three.
The model for the modular curve $X_0(50)$ given in the aforementioned paper is
\begin{equation}
y^2 = x^6 + 2x^5 + 2x^3 + 2x + 1. 
\end{equation}
My problem seems to arise from the fact I can't remove the $x^5$ term when trying to write this in the form of $(1)$.
The only automorphism I have needed to use in previous examples has been $x \mapsto x+c$ for some constant $c \in k$.
However, since $(x+c)^6 = x^6 + 2c^3x^3 + c^6$ in characteristic three this clearly won't work. Are there more subtle/less obvious methods I could use? Or is it not possible to find a model of the form $(1)$ in this manner?

Thanks in advance for any help, and please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a useful observation is that a curve in the form $(1)$ has two distinct automorphisms of order two, namely $x\mapsto -x$ and $y \mapsto -y$. I do not think that a generic hyperelliptic curve has two such automorphisms. The automorphism $y\mapsto -y$ always exists (on your modular curve it corresponds to the Atkin-Lehner involution) but the existence of another automorphism of order $2$ is not so clear.